# Renaming files by folder hierarchy

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have many files with the following structure:

```
1969/ar/1.jpg
1969/ar/2.jpg

1969/he/1.jpg
1969/he/2.jpg

1969/en/1.jpg
1969/en/2.jpg

1970/ar/1.jpg
```

etc...

I want to rename all of them, with one command, to one directory, while their names reflect their original folder location.

```
1969_ar_1.jpg
1969_ar_2.jpg

1969_he_1.jpg
1969_he_2.jpg

1969_en_1.jpg
1969_en_2.jpg

1970_ar_1.jpg
```

etc...

Is it possible to do so with one command or a batch file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do that to move the files to the base folder with this command-line:

```
for /R %a in (*) do @set f=%a& set f=!f:%cd%\=!& move "%a" !f:\=_!
```

Execute it from the folder that contain the 1969, 1970... folders. IMPORTANT!: Delayed Expansion must be active in order for this line to work, so you must previously activate it executing cmd.exe with /V switch this way: `cmd /V`.

For example:

```
>xcopy test backup /s
test\1969\ar\1.jpg
test\1969\ar\2.jpg
test\1969\en\1.jpg
test\1969\en\2.jpg
test\1969\he\1.jpg
test\1969\he\2.jpg
test\1970\ar\1.jpg
7 File(s) copied

>cd test

>dir /B
1969
1970

>for /R %a in (*) do @set f=%a& set f=!f:%cd%\=!& move "%a" !f:\=_!

>dir /B
1969
1969_ar_1.jpg
1969_ar_2.jpg
1969_en_1.jpg
1969_en_2.jpg
1969_he_1.jpg
1969_he_2.jpg
1970
1970_ar_1.jpg
```

Modify the line this way to move the files to another folder:

```
for /R %a in (*) do @set f=%a& set f=!f:%cd%\=!& move "%a" "\other\folder\!f:\=_!"
```

Or via this Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R %%a in (*) do set f=%%a& set f=!f:%cd%\=!& move "%%a" "\other\folder\!f:\=_!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Run this from the base of the tree that contains all *.jpg files.
Change the target folder to where you want the files to go:

Test it on some samples first.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%z in ('dir "*.jpg" /b /s /a-d ') do (
for %%a in ("%%~dpz%\.") do (
for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
  ren "%%z" "%%~nxb_%%~nxa_%%~nxz"
  move "%%~dpz\%%~nxb_%%~nxa_%%~nxz" "c:\target\folder"
)
)
)
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

try this (look at the output and remove the word `echo` before `move`, if it is OK):

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /d %%i in (19* 20*) do (
    cmd /c "for /r "%%i" %%j in (*.jpg) do @for %%k in ("%%~dpj.") do @echo move "%%~j" "%%i_%%~nk_%%~nxj""
)
```

Comment: Had the folder twice (`folder_folder_file`), but worked after removing `%%~nk_` - although I am not perfectly understanding this cool line... Thanks!